# React Native nested Components Touch and Pan interaction

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, touchableopacity

I am having a problem setting up 2 nested Components with 'press' and 'pan gestures'. The `Touchable Component` is supposed to respond to `onPress` events (which is working fine), and the `NativeComponent` is responsible for handling `pan gestures`, the only problem is when I lift my fingers after the pan gesture handled by the NativeComponent, the onPress event by the `Touchable` gets fired, I would like to avoid this.

```
render(){
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.pressFun}>
    <NativeComponent />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
}
```

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated.